# FFmpeg. Generating .ts files and adding metadata to them

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

Before I was following the steps:

1. Create some metadata:

   id3taggenerator -o 1.id3 -artist "Emma Stone"

   id3taggenerator -o 2.id3 -artist "Patricia Clarkson"
2. Create a file saying where to place the metadata in the file:

   68 id3 /path/to/file/1.id3

   78 id3 /path/to/file/2.id3
3. Segment the files and include the metadata

   mediafilesegmenter -f video -M meta.txt video.mp4

More detail:

http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/

I want to do something similar to this, but with FFmpeg.

I am also wondering if I could first segment the file into .ts files and add metadata directly to those?

I am having trouble finding the solution on the website. Any help or resources would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to summarize in your question what exactly "similar to this" is, so people don't have to visit the link to see what you are after.